# script Python que lê um Json e converte em um javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Olá gostaria de uma ajuda,

Tenho um json que posso pegar ela da web ou baixar em meu linux... e preciso montar um codigo padronizado a partir desse json.

Preciso montar um javascript  sempre padrão com as modificações que vem do meu json.

Preciso mudar dois valores no meu javascript.

Hoje atualmente funciona certinho, mais eu que monto manual, queria montar isso de forma automatica usando python ou javascript.

My Json :

```html
{
    "home": [
        {
            "base_url": "home",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "portal": [
        {
            "base_url": "portal",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "digital": [
        {
            "base_url": "digital",
            "redirect_url": "/",
            "type": "www.testemestradoolpt.com.br"
        }

    ]
}
```

Meu JavaScript:

```html
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
     const headers = request.headers;
     const uri = request.uri;

     var origin = request.origin[0].custom.domainName;
     console.log(`Request #PATH# is "${uri}"`);
     console.log(`Request #INCOMING REQUEST ORIGIN# set to "${origin}"`);
    
     const regex = /^\/(digital|home|portal|)[^\/]*/i;  **<<<< ADICIONAR AQUI**
     if (regex.test(request.uri))
     {
             /* Set custom origin fields*/
             request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: 'www.testemestradoolpt.com.br' **<< ADICIONAR AQUI**
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: '*'}];
             /**origin = request.origin.custom.domainName;  enable it for testing*/
    }
    /** for testing purposes don't use unless you need to, big performance hit
    console.log(`###### - > Request HOST "${request.headers.host[0].value}"`);
    console.log(`###### - > Final Request Origin Server "${origin}"`);
    */
    callback(null, request);
};
```

Se vocês repararem eu so preciso adicionar meu base_url que vem dos meus json no campo de expressao regular do javascript e apenas uma vez o type que e a url no outro campo, a url sempre vai ser a mesma.

Eu fiz um script em python que me traz a base url, mais estou precisando de um script em python que monta para min o javascript com as variaveis do json como o java script acima que mandei, e estou tendo muita dificuldade em fazer isso, segue o que consegui fazer em python:

```html
import json

with open('dataload.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data ['home']:
         print(p['base_url'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo como:

```py
regexp = []
url = ''
for key in json:
    for value in json.get(key, []):
        url = value.get('type')
        regexp.append(value.get('base_url'))

regexp = str('|').join(regexp)

js_script = """
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
     const headers = request.headers;
     const uri = request.uri;

     var origin = request.origin[0].custom.domainName;
     console.log(`Request #PATH# is "${uri}"`);
     console.log(`Request #INCOMING REQUEST ORIGIN# set to "${origin}"`);

     const regex = /^\/(""" +  regexp + """|)[^\/]*/i;  **<<<< ADICIONAR AQUI**
     if (regex.test(request.uri))
     {
             /* Set custom origin fields*/
             request.origin = {
                 custom: {
                     domainName: '""" +  url + """' **<< ADICIONAR AQUI**
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: '*'}];
             /**origin = request.origin.custom.domainName;  enable it for testing*/
    }
    /** for testing purposes don't use unless you need to, big performance hit
    console.log(`###### - > Request HOST "${request.headers.host[0].value}"`);
    console.log(`###### - > Final Request Origin Server "${origin}"`);
    */
    callback(null, request);
};
"""

# salvar o arquivo
# ou responder a requisição http com esse script.
```

Você pode criar uma rota em seu servidor que gera e retorna este arquivo pra o cliente.

no cliente (arquivo html) você pode fazer algo como:

```html
<script src="rota/que/retorna/o/script/gerado/dinamicamente"></script>
```

Não sei qual framework que você está usando, mas não se esqueça de definir o `content-type` nos header da resposta como `text/javascript`.

Comment: Uma duvida no campo url"" eu coloco a url do meu json?

fui rodar e surgiu o seguinte erro.

root@LAPTOP-3IP5GPAG:~/cdn/python# python python2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python2.py", line 3, in <module>
    for key in json:
NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Comment: na linha 3 ele itera a variavel `json` que você tem que trocar/ou defini-la com o seu json.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks man!

Comment: mateus pode me ajudar... parece que o topico nao consigo postar mais duvidas... vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Eu fiz essa nova pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/419111/problemas-para-fazer-junção-de-informações-no-meu-script-python